# How to select data in MySQL from the same table based on conditions and avoid duplicates?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, case

I have read related answers, but I did not find a solution to my problem. Please help me with the following issue: I have two tables and I want to match them based on tenors, but considering the fact that in one table I can have different entries satisfying this condition. In the table from which I want to extract the information (inst), I have several data regarding the interest rates, all structured on different lines, e.g. I can either have LIBOR or OIS data. 
I would like to do the following query: to match the tenors from the second table (stgy) with the data from the first table (inst) for the OIS where available, and otherwise, to have the LIBOR data. 
Below a code that I tried and did not work:

```
SELECT  CASE
    WHEN stgy.tenor IN ('1D','1W','2W','3W','1M','2M','3M','4M','5M','6M','7M','8M','9M','10M','11M')
    THEN ( CASE WHEN security_type='OIS' THEN
                (SELECT price_last FROM inst WHERE currency = @base_crncy AND trade_date = @date_of_interest AND tenor = stgy.tenor)
            ELSE
                (SELECT price_last
               FROM inst                                                                                  
              WHERE security_type IN  ('LIBOR') AND currency = @base_crncy AND trade_date = @date_of_interest
            ) 
            END AS rate 
        )
       ELSE NULL
END AS int_rate
```

I am also matching on the same trading day and currency. Please consider that I can have other security_type as well. Thank you for your help!

Updated query:

```
     SELECT CASE WHEN stgy.tenor IN('1D','1W','2W','3W','1M','2M','3M','4M','5M','6M','7M','8M','9M','10M','11M')      
      THEN (COALESCE((SELECT price_last FROM instruments WHERE security_type='OIS' AND currency=@base_crncy AND trade_date = @date_of_interest AND tenor=stgy.tenor),
                        (SELECT price_last FROM instruments WHERE security_type='LIBOR' AND currency = @base_crncy AND trade_date = @date_of_interest AND tenor=stgy.tenor)) 
                      )
        ELSE NULL

        END AS int_rate
-- and here i add from where based on the join between the tables (this part works)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to simplify, you appear to want to query from your "stgy" table just for the specific base currency AND the "tenor" values in the list.

```
SELECT
      s.tenor
   FROM 
      stgy s
   WHERE 
          s.currency = @base_crncy
      AND s.tenor IN ('1D', '1W', '2W', '3W', '1M', '2M', '3M', '4M',
                      '5M', '6M', '7M', '8M', '9M', '10M', '11M')
```

from that, you want the rate from the "inst" table on same tenor, currency and date of trade.  Now, to get the last price, it is based on the SECURITY TYPE.

```
SELECT
      s.tenor, 
      COALESCE( i.price_last, i2.price_last ) as Price_Last
   FROM 
      stgy s
         LEFT JOIN inst i
            ON s.currency = i.currency
           AND s.tenor = i.tenor
           AND i.trade_date = @date_of_interest 
           AND i.securityType = 'OIS' 
         LEFT JOIN inst i2
            ON s.currency = i2.currency
           AND i2.trade_date = @date_of_interest 
           AND i2.securityType = 'LIBOR' 
   WHERE 
          s.currency = @base_crncy
      AND s.tenor IN ('1D', '1W', '2W', '3W', '1M', '2M', '3M', '4M',
                      '5M', '6M', '7M', '8M', '9M', '10M', '11M')
```

To help optimize the query, I would include an index on

```
stgy   ( currency, tenor )
inst   ( currency, trade_date, tenor, security_type )
```

Syntax for creating the indexes...

```
ALTER TABLE `stgy` ADD INDEX `currency_tenor` (`currency`, `tenor` );
ALTER TABLE `inst` ADD INDEX `cur_trade_ten_sec` (`currency`, `trade_date, `tenor`, `security_type` );
```

Now, you may need to tweek the condition for:

```
       AND case when s.securityType = 'OIS' 
                then s.tenor = i.tenor
                else s.security_type IN ('LIBOR') end
```

as you do not show table structures, nor sample data (you can edit your original question to provide such SAMPLE data.

Also, you mention preventing duplicates...  By duplicates, do you mean multiple entries for a given currency, trade_date, tenor, security type (also unsure which table your "security_type" field is actually associated with).

I modified by doing TWO left-joins to the inst table.  Please confirm the required criteria respectively.  It looked like your "OIS" criteria required the join on the "tenor" field too, but NOT for the "LIBOR" value.  But notice the left joins are explicitly on EITHER the "OIS" or "LIBOR" respectively so there should not be multiple entries for a given OIS/TENOR, nor a duplicate on LIBOR per given date/currency.

Then, the price is pulled via COALESCE().  If the first value is NULL, then grab the value from the second column.  If that too is null, your final column answer would be null which is what you intended to get.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. security_type is associated with table inst. I actually provided only a part of the query, as I later join the two tables, similarly as  you did above. By duplicates, I was referring to the fact that I can have data for those tenors in both OIS and LIBOR, but I want to retrieve the data from OIS and in case it does not have some of the tenors, then I want LIBOR data. Obviously, the situation is different depending on the currency and the trading date so I would need a general formula. Is there a way to do it by avoiding the join? Thank you.

Comment: @Astrid, so is the "OIS" the PRIMARY consideration, and if no such entry exists, it should fall-back to the "LIBOR" as secondary?  Such as the table COULD have both values per given tenor?

Comment: What you stated is correct. The table in general has both values per given tenor, but I would like to retrieve the one for OIS and in case is missing, then the LIBOR. In case LIBOR is also missing, then NULL. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Astrid, see revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, DRapp!

Comment: @Astrid, if that worked, mark as such so others know it is solved.

Comment: DRapp, I tried your approach but it takes a long time to run the query. However, I did not include the index as I am not familiar with. I have updated the original question with what I tried instead and seems to work (at least faster). Could you please let me know your opinion?

Comment: @Astrid, I updated my answer to show syntax for creating the additional indexes for you.